# How to convert string containing dictionary to a dictionary?

Tags: python

Could anyone help me and explain to me why I keep getting an error?
I have a string formatted as a dictionary. Similar to the below:

```
str1_dict="{Sentence:Frequently Asked Questions AND PRIVACY ,Question:What is the most frequently asked question about privacy?,Answer0:Frequently,Question:What does Privacy stand for?,Answer1:PRIVACY}"
```

I implemented a function that accepts the `str1_dict` and returns a value ( e.g., value of  the key `"Sentence."`)
Every time I run this function on the string `str1_dict`, I get the error:

```
  File "<string>", line 1
    {Sentence:Frequently Asked Questions AND PRIVACY ,Question:What is the most frequently asked question about privacy?,Answer0:Frequently,Question:What does Privacy stand for?,Answer1:PRIVACY}
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here is my code:

```
import json

str1_dict="{Sentence:Frequently Asked Questions AND PRIVACY ,Question:What is the most frequently asked question about privacy?,Answer0:Frequently,Question:What does Privacy stand for?,Answer1:PRIVACY}"

def Read_dict(Data):
     line_tmp= Data.replace('\n','')
     jsn = eval(line_tmp)
     #jsn = json.loads(line_tmp)
     #jsn= ast.literal_eval(line_tmp)
     return jsn['Sentence']

 Read_dict(str1_dict)
```

I tried all the methods that I found online for converting string to dictionary, such as  `eval()`, `json.loads()`, and `ast.literal_eval()`, but all of them failed. I keep getting the same error.

Can someone explain to me what wrong with my code or string?

Comment: The problem is that your string is not valid JSON, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Syntax)

Comment: The string needs to have quotes inside: `'{"Sentence":"Something"}'`

Comment: @Programmer thanks for help. you'r right!

Comment: @JohnGordon, thanks for the help. You're right. I just formatted the string-like what you mentioned. It works! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your string does not contain valid JSON. You can use this function to parse your invalid JSON in a dictionary:

```py
def str2dict(data):
    data = data.strip(" {}") # get rid of brackets and spaces at the start an end
    key_value_pair_strings = data.split(",") # split data at , into key value pair strings
    key_value_pair_strings_stripped = list(map(str.strip, key_value_pairs)) # strip whitespaces from the key value pair strings
    key_value_pairs = list(map(lambda s: s.split(":"), key_value_pair_strings)) # get key value pairs by splitting each key value pair string at :
   return dict(key_value_pairs)

result = str2dict("{Sentence:Frequently Asked Questions AND PRIVACY ,Question:What is the most frequently asked question about privacy?,Answer0:Frequently,Question:What does Privacy stand for?,Answer1:PRIVACY}")
print(result["Sentence"])
```

The whole function body can be reduced to one line !

```py
def str2dict_one_line(data):
    return dict(list(map(lambda s: s.split(":"), list(map(str.strip, data.strip(" {}").split(","))))))

result = str2dict_one_line("{Sentence:Frequently Asked Questions AND PRIVACY ,Question:What is the most frequently asked question about privacy?,Answer0:Frequently,Question:What does Privacy stand for?,Answer1:PRIVACY}")
print(result["Sentence"])
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the correct apostrophes:

On popular demand, you can also do this:

```
import json
str1_dict='{"Sentence": "Frequently Asked Questions AND PRIVACY" ,"Question": "What is the most frequently asked question about privacy?", "Answer0": "Frequently", "Question": "What does Privacy stand for?", "Answer1": "PRIVACY"}'
json.loads(str1_dict)
```

You can also use eval but know that it might not be safe and should be avoided or used with caution depending on your usecase:

```
str1_dict="{'Sentence': 'Frequently Asked Questions AND PRIVACY', 'Question': 'What is the most frequently asked question about privacy?', 'Answer0': 'Frequently', 'Question': 'What does Privacy stand for?', 'Answer1': 'PRIVACY'}"
eval(str1_dict)
```

Comment: If you're going to add quotation marks, you might as well add the ones that make this valid JSON so that `eval` isn't necessary.

Comment: Yes, it is relevant to the question. Any reasonable answer to this question should include the obligatory "this is not a use case for `eval`". Our goal is to teach people, not just put out their fires.